# How to keep asking for input while it is in between 0-8 and is not contained in the hash set

Tags: java

I'm having an issue where I want to keep asking the user for input while it is between 0-8, and if it isn't, or if it's already in the hash set, to ask it again.

```
HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>(9);
                list = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);

    System.out.println("\n Enter your own 8-Puzzle Configuration of non-repeating numbers ranging from 0-8.");

                int num = 0;
                int i = 0;

                do {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter #" + i + ": ");
                        num = kb.nextInt();

                        if (hash.contains(num)) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("This is number was already entered. Please try again.");
                            System.out.println("Enter #" + i + ": ");
                            num = kb.nextInt();
                        }
                        if (num <= 0 || num > 8) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("# must be in the range of 0-8.");
                            System.out.println("Enter #" + i + ": ");
                            num = kb.nextInt();
                        }
                        list.add(num);
                        hash.add(num);
                        i++;
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                        System.out.println("Not a valid number. Try again");
                    }
                    kb.nextLine();
                } while (i < 9);
```

Comment: *"while it is between 0-8, and if it isn't, or if it's already in the hash set, to ask it again."* I'm confused, while it is and isn't between 0-8??

Comment: Yeah, was just going to say the same thing.  Your spec is a bit confused.  When do you stop asking the user for more numbers?  Because regardless whether it is or isn't between 0 and 8, you always seem to want to ask again.

Comment: You stop asking the user for inputs after each number from 0-8 has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

You were adding incorrect values if two incorrect values were added in a row. Also, you don't need to use a set - the ArrayList also has a `contains` method.

```
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(9);
        System.out.println("\n Enter your own 8-Puzzle Configuration of non-repeating numbers ranging from 0-8.");

        do {
            int index = list.size() + 1;
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter #" + index + ": ");
                int num = kb.nextInt();

                if (list.contains(num)) {
                    System.out
                            .println("This is number was already entered. Please try again.");
                } else if (num <= 0 || num > 8) {
                    System.out.println("# must be in the range of 0-8.");
                } else {
                    list.add(num);
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid number. Try again");
            }
        } while (list.size() < 8);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!! I don't know why this was so hard for me to figure out. Appreciate it.